# Performance problems for WCF Services on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, wcf, windows-phone-8

I'm going to make a Windows Phone 8 app which gets his data from a WCF Services. Now I'm just starting with WP 8 development and I'm begging to wonder if WCF is my best choice. After all wsdl services send a lot of xml extra data and formatting with every response which is not the best thing for a phone app. My question is: Is it ok to use WCF with its big XML responses or I should try something else, like maybe httpHandlers that return JSON data with maybe dynamic gzip responses? Not sure if they will work with WP8, but like I said I'm wondering what is the right direction to point my self to.

Comment: WCF does not per se mean that you have to use XML. It can easily produce responses in json (or tcp).

Comment: yes, but still does that mean its ok to use WCF that return JSON for WP8?

Comment: Huh? The "overhead" of SOAP does not apply to JSON. The overhead of SOAP isn't caused by WCF - it's caused by SOAP.

Comment: ok, so we got two votes for WCF with JSON responses..  :)

Comment: If you're writing a new application, use the WebAPI: http://www.asp.net/web-api Don't write it your self.

Comment: I would go with WCF with JSON. It is fairly lightweight as it's only a string. There are plenty of JSON parsing utilities as well, if you don't like the default ones.

Comment: In general there are just two reasons to use WCF over other choices: wsdl and wide transport support (net.tcp and pipes). So if you need an HTTP service and don't care about wsdl, I would choose WebApi. Both of them could be self-hosted or IIS-hosted. WCF is bit easier to integrate with Windows authentication but WebAPI is easier to learn. So I vote for WebAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I decided to go with WCF and JSON responses to connect to my windows phone 8 App.. I didn't exactly choose WCF it was kind of part of the assignment, but I am going to use the build in authentication and authorization system of WCF with user credentials.. I'm going to serialize the response every time in JSON format and then GZIP it when returning it. With my modest testing it turns out to be quiet fast. If someone else is wondering with this here is some sample code (I'm using JSON.NET):

```
private string GetSuppliersLite()
    {
        // Get the ObjectContext that is the data source for the service.
        NorthwindEntities context = this.CurrentDataSource;

        try
        {
            var suppliers = (from s in context.Suppliers
                             select new
                             {
                                 Address = s.Address,
                                 City = s.City,
                                 CompanyName = s.Company_Name,
                                 ContactName = s.Contact_Name,
                                 ContactTitle = s.Contact_Title,
                                 Country = s.Country,
                                 Fax = s.Fax,
                                 Phone = s.Phone,
                                 PostalCode = s.Postal_Code,
                                 Region = s.Region,
                                 SupplierID = s.Supplier_ID,
                             }
                            ).ToList();

            string jsonClient = null;
            JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
            jsonSerializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            jsonSerializer.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
            jsonSerializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error;
            try
            {
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (JsonTextWriter jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        jsonSerializer.Serialize(jtw, suppliers);
                    }
                    jsonClient = sw.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex = ex; // have a breakpoint here so can inspect exception
            }
            return jsonClient;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format(
                "An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }

    [WebGet]
    public string GetSuppliersLiteZip()
    {
        return Zip(GetSuppliersLite());
    }

    private string Zip(string value)
    {
        //Transform string into byte[]  
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[value.Length];
        int indexBA = 0;
        foreach (char item in value.ToCharArray())
        {
            byteArray[indexBA++] = (byte)item;
        }

        //Prepare for compress
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sw = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);

        //Compress
        sw.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        //Close, DO NOT FLUSH cause bytes will go missing...
        sw.Close();

        //Transform byte[] zip data to string
        byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(byteArray.Length);
        foreach (byte item in byteArray)
        {
            sB.Append((char)item);
        }
        ms.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        ms.Dispose();
        return sB.ToString();
    }
```